# ctx.rotate() without using ctx.save and ctx.restore

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to avoid using ctx.save() and ctx.restore() every time I call my drawing function, and change the context settings only when needed.
The idea is instead of reseting all the context settings to 0, I check if each setting needs to change and I change it according to its value.
(The aim is to check if it is faster than using save and restore in some situations.)
I tried this way :

```
function draw_pic( pic_id , x , y , angle , scale , opacity )
{
    if( x!=previous_x || y!=previous_y )
    {   ctx.translate( x-previous_x , y-previous_y );
        previous_x = x ; previous_y = y ; }

    if( angle!=previous_angle )
    {   ctx.rotate( (angle-previous_angle) * Math.PI / 180 );
        previous_angle = angle ; }

    if( scale!=previous_scale )
    {   ctx.scale( scale , scale );
        previous_scale = scale ; }

    if( opacity!=previous_opacity )
    {   ctx.globalAlpha = opacity ;
        previous_opacity = opacity ; }

    ctx.drawImage( images_obj[pic_id] , - images_infos[pic_id].origin_x , - images_infos[pic_id].origin_y );
}
```

Everything seems ok except the rotation part. As soon as I want my images to be drawn with different angles they are drawn in a mess jumping all around the screen...   What is the problem ?

All the examples I find on the web use save() and restore() so they always start from 0, I do not find any example that deals with the previous values like I am trying to do.

Comment: Does it also skip around if you keep the scaling fixed at 1? Also, you might have a typo there too, it never seem to scale down. I think you need to scale it to `scale/previous_scale`

Answer (score 0):

It might be so easy to replace "rotate" in your if-statement with "angle"

Before:

```
if( rotate!=previous_angle ) {   
    ctx.rotate( (angle-previous_angle) * Math.PI / 180 );
    previous_angle = angle; 
}
```

After:

```
if( angle!=previous_angle ) {   
    ctx.rotate( (angle-previous_angle) * Math.PI / 180 );
    previous_angle = angle; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this typo. However the typo was only in the post, not in my actual function, so this does not solve the problem. :\